# Will cars annual service light still come on if I do an early service?

Tags: service, warning-light, jaguar, servicing

I have a Jaguar XJ 2010 model, the service warning light comes on around October every year for the annual service. If however I was to get it serviced in June this year (i.e earlier than the service is due and before the light comes on) will it ignore and skip this year? Or will it still come on in October? i.e Do car systems just turn the light on after a certain year regardless if it has been serviced previously or even if there has not been much mileage done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive how the Jaguar system runs, but would assume the service light comes on when the time period has elapsed, and is then *reset* by the technician. If you take it in for service and have the maintenance done on it, the technician should reset it and the light should not come on for another year from that point. Ask your tech to reset the computer when you get the maintenance done and the *dreaded* service light should be avoided :D